# EJS not identifying double quotes

Tags: ejs, package.json

I'm trying to replace a piece of code in package.json using ejs. So far the code works but only hiccup is, double quotes are replaced with """ in the place of double quotes.
Here is the code:

package.json code snippet:

```
"devDependencies": {
<% switch (webFramework) {
  case 'express': %>
    <%= include(root + '/templates/partials/package_express_dev') %>
<% break;
  case 'koa': %>
  <%= include( root + '/templates/partials/package_koa_dev') %>
<% break; } %>
...}
```

package_koa_dev.ejs code snippet:

```
"@koa/cors": "^4.0.0",
"koa": "^2.14.1",
"koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
"koa-cookie": "^1.0.0",
"koa-json": "^2.0.2",
"koa-passport": "^6.0.0",
"koa-router": "^12.0.0",
"koa-session": "^6.4.0"
```

and the output I get:

```
&#34;@koa/cors&#34;: &#34;^4.0.0&#34;,
&#34;koa&#34;: &#34;^2.14.1&#34;,
&#34;koa-bodyparser&#34;: &#34;^4.3.0&#34;,
&#34;koa-cookie&#34;: &#34;^1.0.0&#34;,
&#34;koa-json&#34;: &#34;^2.0.2&#34;,
&#34;koa-passport&#34;: &#34;^6.0.0&#34;,
&#34;koa-router&#34;: &#34;^12.0.0&#34;,
&#34;koa-session&#34;: &#34;^6.4.0&#34;
```

any suggestions to how this issue can be fixed?